# Выдаёт ошибку подключения к базам данных

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Не могу найти ошибку, перепробовал всё, ошибка скорее всего где-то в самом синтаксисе Php.

> Ошибка подключения к базе данных! php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

```
<?php
if (!preg_match("/^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/",$_COOKIE['hash']) && $_COOKIE['hash'] != ""){
    exit('cookie hack detected');
}
else{
$servername = "http://d982943z.beget.tech/";
$bd_login = 'user'; //логин базы данных

$bd_pass = 'password'; //пароль базы данных

$bd_name = 'd982943z_e'; //имя базы данных
 
$db = mysqli_connect($servername, $bd_login, $bd_pass, $bd_name)//параметры в скобках ("хост", "имя пользователя", "пароль")
or die("<p>Ошибка подключения к базе данных! " . mysqli_connect_error() . "</p>");
mysqli_query($db,"SET NAMES utf8");
mysqli_select_db($db, 'support');
}
?>
```

P.S. Если у кого есть возможность помочь можно в вк vk.com/cooladi

Comment: уберите логины пароли из текста

Comment: @splash58 пробовал, не помогло. Или надо полностью убрать $bd_pass и $bd_login?

Comment: я про то, что не надо светить права доступа на весь интернет. Или вам не жаль?

Comment: Данный пароль нигде не используется)

Comment: вот это `, "localhost"`  снесите - https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.construct.php

Comment: Появилась вот такая ошибка:Ошибка подключения к базе данных! php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known @splash58

Comment: Обычно на хостингах нужно указывать адрес сервера mysql. И этот адрес можно посмотреть а панели администирования

Comment: А где можно найти этот адрес? @AntonShchyrov

Comment: @TINESY  В поисковике пропишите название вашей панели управления и дословно "Адрес сервера Mysql " и чудо не заставит себя ждать.